# Decimal conversion number of the form x.xx to 0x.xx, sed?

Tags: text-processing

I have a file of the form

```
...
num  0.12 num num 
num 25.53 num num
num  7.82 num num
...
```

and I want to convert the 2nd field of each line adding a "0" at the numbers >= 0 and < 10 so the output will have the form:

```
...
num 00.12 num num
num 25.53 num nnum  
num 07.82 num num
...
```

I tried with

```
sed 's/ 7./07./2'
```

but it is not white space sensitive so it replaces any occurance of "7."

Answer (score 5):

With `awk`:

```
$ awk '$2 = sprintf("%05.2f",$2)' file
num 00.12 num num
num 25.53 num num
num 07.82 num num
```

Answer (score 3):

What you are after is probably something like:

```
sed 's/ \([0-9]\.\)/0\1/'
```

It matches a space followed by one digit from the range 0 to 9 followed by a dot and replaces the space by the 0. The parentheses `\([0-9]\.\)` mark a group which is referenced by `\1` in the replacement part of the expression.

Answer (score 2):

What if you use `awk`?

```awk
$ awk '$2>0 && $2<10 {$2="0"$2}1' file
num 00.12 num num
num 25.53 num num
num 07.82 num num
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure shell:

```
while read a b rest; do 
    b=$(printf "%05.2f" $b); 
    echo "$a $b $rest";
done < file.txt
```

Comment: You don't need `second` variable, just `echo "$a" "$(printf "%05.2f" $b)" "$rest"`

Comment: @Gnouc true, but I find it more readable.

Comment: @Gnouc - you don't need any variables. `printf '%.2f %05.2f %.2f %.2f\n' $(cat <file)`